# For loop not operating correctly

Tags: python, list, loops

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with sorting out why this code:

```
counter=0
fruits=['apple','pear','orange','grape']
for i in fruits:
    print(fruits[counter])
    counter=+1
```

only prints:

```
apple
pear
pear
pear
```

rather than each of the fruits in the list.

Comment: `counter=+1` should be `counter+=1`. Otherwise, you're setting `counter` to be positive 1 with each iteration. And index 1 of `fruits` is `'pear'`

Comment: Also you don't need it, `i` is already `fruits[counter]`.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `a=+1` you're setting a equal to positive 1. You want `a+=1`.

Or, you could just print `i` instead of using a counter since `i` is already iterating through the items in the list.

Example using a counter:

```
counter = 0
fruits = ['apple','pear','orange','grape']
for i in fruits:
    print(fruits[counter])
    counter += 1
```

Cleaner example without a counter:

```
fruits = ['apple','pear','orange','grape']
for i in fruits:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code.

`counter += 1` should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to index in this situation with Python. You can amend as follows:

```
fruits=['apple','pear','orange','grape']

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit)
```

As mentioned, you are assigning the `counter` to +1 (`=+1`) instead of incrementing it (`+=1`). It will thus print the second element (the `1` index) after the first time for the duration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the `counter` variable, if it is a requirement then use `counter += 1` instead of `counter = +1`

The solution for what you want is:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'grape']
for f in fruits:
    print(f)
```